# Regenerate Netbeans Forms

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a Java novice. Some years ago, I lost the source code of a Java prog but fortunately its compiled jars were safe to run and work.

I happened to recover the code with the help of Procyon (procyon-decompiler-0.5.30), tweaked it a little and it started to work as usual again.

Unfortunately, I could see the GUI at run time but couldn't trace a hint of it by searching in vain for a "design view" tab in Netbeans 8.2 (while it was actually coded in Netbeans 7,  if I could recall correctly).

In short, I soon found that the form files which are normally generated by Netbeans for a GUI app, are missing anyway and, once lost, could no more be generated by Netbeans. Finally, I found that the same could be done by using another tool, FormGenerator and now that I'm using the latter, I'm facing a lot more difficulties because it's complaining a lot!

Kindly, examine the accompanying scree shots and offer any help you can. Thanks.

Form Generator says this:
[Message Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWH7.png)

And this is a verbose list of errors while trying to input the forms:
[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJFVe.png)

Comment: There's no real way you can reverse engineer the UI code so design former can use it. The design former relies on configuration files which are only part of the source

Comment: I would a little bit disagree because if accepted what you remarked then it would mean that no UI be generated from the code at run time because in theory at least both the design time and run time UI's should be drawn the same way. The problem is of imprinting the run time UI permanently onto something sticky!

Comment: Netbeans generates code at design time, which is the compiled and executed, no ui is generated from the "form designer" configuration at run time, it's only controlled at design time, since netbeans relies on the firm designer file that accompanies the source file, once that's lost, it can't be regenerated, that doesn't mean the ui code that it created in code doesn't exist, only that the settings the the form designer needs is gone - time to learn how to code uis by hand :P

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Any idea about FormGenerator I mentioned earlier? What's it used for then, if forms can't be regenerated from the source code??